# Tensed verb in Subjunctive Clause

Tags: subjunctives

Subjunctive Clause calls for a plain verb form to be used as predicate.

1. It still can be realized via «should» and even with the Tensed Verb (number and person indication). Though in two latter cases, it ceases to be subjunctive any more, if am not mistaken.

It is desirable that we be present.

It is desirable that we shall be present.

It is desirable that we are present.

Does grammar permits usage of true «Tensed Verb» (number, person and tense)? if so, does still remain to be Sunjunctive Clause?

It is desirable that we will be present.

It was desirable that we were present.

2. The same hold true for Purpose Clause

Max leaves the door open so that the cat might go outside

```
                                       so that the cat can go outside

                                       so that the cat shall go outside

                                       so that the cat will go outside

                                       so that the cat ____ goes outside  ?????
```

Is the latter sentence grammatically correct?

Thank you for support!

Comment: "Subjuncitve" is a name given to a set of verb conjugations in various language. Apart from the single form _were_ there is no such conjugation in modern English. What you call a "subjunctive clause" means " a clause which, if I were to translated it into certain other languages, would be expressed with a subjunctive  verb". The term makes no sense in English.

Comment: OK, thank you! if am wrong, then would you use "it is desirable that we will be present".? Is that correct?

Comment: 1) *Max leaves the door open so the cat **goes** outside* = Max **wanted** the cat to go out, and he left the door open ***in order to achieve that desired outcome***. In that scenario, what the cat itself wants is irrelevant, so long as it does actually leave through the open door. 2) *Max leaves the door open so the cat **can go** outside* = Max is simply making it ***possible*** for the cat to go out (if it wants), even though Max himself may not particularly care what the cat chooses to do.